# How can i list a number, which this number is gave from user, in Python 2.7.14?

Tags: python-2.7, list, numbers

More accurately, I ask user for a number and after I want to list this number so i can use it for my code!

This is the part of my code i want help:

```
num=int(raw_input("Give me a number: "))
(*)                                    (*)
#(*)...(*) is the part I want help!
```

Comment: what's wrong with above code?

Comment: I want to list this number.

Comment: use list to store the numbers. Use your code in a for loop and keep adding numbers to the list.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    numbers = []
num = int(raw_input('give me a number'))
numbers.append(num)
print numbers
```

or keep add items to the list :

```
    numbers = []
while True:
    num = int(raw_input('give me a number'))
    numbers.append(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the input is 10 20 30 40 50

you ca get the input as follows

```
number=map(int,raw_input("Enter the list of numbers:").split())
print number
```

this will have
number=[10,20,30,40,50]